# Get the last status on 1 day timeframe on tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I'd like to build a dropdown strategy.
for example, IF the last candle `crossover` ema200 the color is yellow,
IF the last candle `crossunder` ema200 the color is black.
IF the last candle doesn't cross ema, the candle has default color.

When I move on 4h timeframe, I'd like to have some label only if the last candle has yellow body.
If the last candle has black body, the logic of yellow body on 4h timeframe is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study("ema200 cross")

ema200 = ema(close, 200)
crossUp = crossover(close, ema200)
crossDown = crossunder(close, ema200)

// crossema up - yellow, down - black, nothing happened - no color
color candleColor = crossUp ? color.yellow : crossDown ? color.black : na

// grab the daily data. delayed by 1 D candle (candleColor[1]) to avoid repaint issues
colDaily = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", candleColor[1], false, true)

// colorize the bars in candleColor. If the Daily bar is yellow and we cross down on current timeframe(black) - no color
barcolor(crossDown and colDaily == color.yellow ? na : candleColor)

// plot the current timeframe ema in the Daily candleColor.
plot(ema200, color = na(colDaily) ? color.blue : colDaily)
```